# Saving data SQL Server in Android Appication without Web Services, API

Tags: android, sql-server-2014

How I can saving data SQL Server (insert into by query excute) in Android Appication without Web Services, API

Comment: You should use an API to communicate with your backend database, can you explain why you don't want to use a webservice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JDBC

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server

It is not advised as Android devices lack in processing power for such operations. Uneed to use WebAPi/web services for such things.

Comment: when I'm using it
And get error "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" when go to this:                   
DbConn  = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);

My code
~
 String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://112.197.0.71;DatabaseName=Vinasino_eSky4DApp";
            String username = "patsoft";
            String password = "P@ts0ft";
            String address = "'"+ Longitude +" " +Latitude +"'";
            Connection DbConn = null ;// DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://112.197.0.71/Vinasino_eSky4DApp;user=" + username + ";password=" + password);
~